# handleSubmit is not running React - Redux Form - handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm making a gallery app using react-redux, react-redux-firebase.
Now, working on Login form and handleSubmit is not triggered. 
However, handleChange works just fine. Could someone help me?

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


export class SignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { email: "", password: "" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    console.log("onchange");
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
    this.props.signIn(this.state);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="sign-in">
        <ul className="active-or-not">
          <li className="active-user">
            <Link to="/Sign-in">Sign in</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="not-active-user">
            <Link to="/Registration">New</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div className="container">
          <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="input-field">
              <input
                placeholder="Email"
                className="input"
                type="email"
                id="email"
                pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
              <input
                placeholder="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                pattern="^\S*$"
                maxLength="20"
                className="input"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
              <button type="submit" className="submit">
                Go
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Onchange triggered collectly and console shows result, but when clicked submit button nothing shows up. 
I've been trying to see similar problem but can't find the actual idea how to fix it.

Comment: Just tested your code, and works fine for me. It was showing the value `clicked` on the console.

Comment: @norbitrial Hi, thanks, mine is still not working, would it be because of redux or firebase...?